# How to Disable some Date's for Long Events in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

We Display Classes (Music, Language,..) in Full Calendar plugin. Class Duration is 3 months. We need to hide holidays dates in Calendar view.  my code below.

```
"events": [
    {
      "title": "selected dates Events",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-16T15:03:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 16, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/selected-dates-events/",
      "post_id": 536,
      "multi_day": "selected",
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "selected dates Events",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-23T15:03:00",
      "unformated_date": "",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/selected-dates-events/",
      "post_id": 536,
      "multi_day": "selected",
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "selected dates Events",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-25T15:03:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 25, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/selected-dates-events/",
      "post_id": 536,
      "multi_day": "selected",
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "selected dates Events",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-26T15:03:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 26, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/selected-dates-events/",
      "post_id": 536,
      "multi_day": "selected",
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "selected dates Events",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-29T15:03:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 29, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/selected-dates-events/",
      "post_id": 536,
      "multi_day": "selected",
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "New Kick Boxing Product 1233",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-23T00:00:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 23, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/new-kick-boxing-product-1233/",
      "post_id": 535,
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "end": "2024-04-19T00:00:00",
      "unformated_end_date": "April 19, 2024",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    },
    {
      "title": "Kick Boxing Test",
      "allDay": false,
      "start": "2022-06-20T03:02:00",
      "unformated_date": "June 20, 2022",
      "url": "http://localhost:8888/boxingstudio/product/kick-boxing-test/",
      "post_id": 531,
      "color": "#16a75d",
      "textColor": "#ffffff",
      "end": "2022-07-18T14:02:00",
      "unformated_end_date": "July 18, 2022",
      "in_stock": "yes"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What about if 2022-06-23 is on holidays... ¿Should you see 'New Kick Boxing Product 1233' event, or not?

Comment: You can tell fullCalendar to hide weekends, but other arbitrary dates cannot be fully hidden. All you can do is something like making a feed of background events which contain the holidays, so that these dates would be highlighted on the calendar in a different colour, to show they are holidays.

Comment: Someone asked something almost identical just recently, so I've closed your question as a duplicate of that, the solutions will really be the same.